# Google Analytics Mobile and window.analytics.setUserId('my-user-id')

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-analytics

I'm using the Google Analytics Cordova plugin [here](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin). On the documentation, it just says this:

**To set a UserId:**

```
window.analytics.setUserId('my-user-id')
```

How does this work? Do I need to pass in a value to replace `'my-used-id'`, and if so which value? Do I even need to call this function for the plugin to work or do I just call `window.analytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXX-YY')` in the `deviceready` function and then just use `window.analytics.trackView('Screen Title')` to track screens? Do I call this every time my app starts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User id is way to bind certain user to the tracking data without being able to identify the user. So you basically count some kind of hash from user's username etc to pass for *window.analytics.setUserId* **in case you wish to use that feature**. You can read more about user id [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id?hl=fi).

However it is not necessary at all and just to get the analytics up and running, you need to simply call *analytics.startTrackerWithId* with your *UA-* starting id (your Google Analytics Mobile App property). After that when you navigate through your application, you can use *analytics.trackView* to inform Google Analytics about it for it to collect that information.

So short answers to your key questions as a summary:

**No**, you don't need to add *window.analytics.setUserId*. If you decide that you need the analytics about how user moves on multiple times he/she opens the app, you can count some hash from username (or etc) to use as parameter for that.

**Yes**, call *window.analytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXX-YY')* every time your app starts (on *deviceready* event), and after that *window.analytics.trackView('Screen Title')* for each screen.

Comment: Don't forget that you also might need user's agreement, and/or privacy policy for your app if you do this. Be sure to read requirements by given app store. If you store user's id, this might count as "personally identifiable information" (PII) and might have different legal requirements than anonymous tracking.

Answer (score 2):

You just call it one time only everytime the app launch.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use device APIs
    window.analytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXX-YY')
}
```

Track screen you need to insert each page that you want to track.

Page 1

```
window.analytics.trackView('Page 1')
```

Page 2

```
window.analytics.trackView('Page 2')
```

Page 3

```
window.analytics.trackView('Page 3')
```

User Id is your user that use your app. You can grab it from your database.

```
window.analytics.setUserId('1')
```